# Google Cloud: when creating a VM, "create" is not active

Tags: google-compute-engine

Have started setting up a Google Compute VM-node, following a 'hello-word' tutorial.

To my surprise it seems like the "create" button is not active. To illustrate this oddity, here is a screen-shot

[image]

Does anyone have a clue for why 'I am not allowed' to construct such an instance? It could be the web-browsers: tested both Chromium and Firefox using Ubuntu-LTS 12.04, though to no avail.

Comment: You can check the permissions in your project to make sure your user account has owner or editor permissions at least, to create the VM instance. You can refer to this doc (https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/access#usersproject) for more information on project permissions.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your time looking into the issue: sadly it turns out that the problem is hidden 'somewhere in the user-database of Google-Cloud': Google-clouds support-team is currently on the task, ie, I will update this post when 'the bug has been sought out': challenge is that the problem/bug seems cantered around the current account, if other have ideas of 'approaches'/work-arounds, I would be thankful if you would put them forward.

Comment: The the issue is resolved: using the "gcloud" tool the bug was 'provoked', ie, turned out being the same issue Michele and Faizan (above) found a 'work-around' for. (For details, see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gce-discussion/wl1P9UjdJko). Therefore utmost thankful to the support-team at Google-Cloud: they are the best ;)

Comment: I'm glad to know that your issue has been resolved. You can post the solution as an answer and accept it, which will help other users with the same issue.

Comment: Wilco: omitted it, ie, as it was strictly speaking your suggestion (in a different forum) which resolved it. However, ie, given your humbleness, I for sure will do: thanks for the help! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue resolved, ie, thanks to Google Clouds support team.

In brief, what solved the issue was to use the bash/terminal API to identify the bug, a bug which was resolved through the creation/construction of a new network (ie, at the network-tab in Google Clouds web-based menu).

**Steps taken:**

step1: use the "gcloud" tool (https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/create)

step2: search the web for the following warning: "ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.create) Some requests did not succeed: ... Resource was not found"

step3: follow instructions at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gce-discussion/wl1P9UjdJko

Comment: Just dropping in to say thank you for coming back and posting the solution. Cheers!